# ActionController::UnknownFormat in MeetingsController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have read countless SO questions about this issue, and can not find a solution.

I have a button that updates Meeting here:

```
 <%= form_for(meeting) do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :accepted, value: true %>
   <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn_primary") do %>
        Accept <svg><use xlink:href="#checkmark"/></svg>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

I get an unknown format error, BUT it still updates. What is causing this error?

I have tried removing  `respond_to do |format|` from the update method. which solves the problem for this one button, but then breaks all the other buttons on the platform that calls meetings/update.

```
class MeetingsController < ApplicationController

 respond_to :json, :html 

  def update
    respond_to do |format|    **error highlights this line**
      if @meeting.update(meeting_params)
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @meeting }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @meeting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
 end
```

Console:

```
Started PATCH "/meetings/224" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-11 16:05:27 -0500
Processing by MeetingsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hK6AoOZuw9DWyKUXw1dXWOSUolooWgBUPnkItUJX5Tm7XvimsHd9518pkqwVvNhUi3L3vlA4OZaJZiAgrbS0Ig==", "meeting"=>{"accepted"=>"true"}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"224"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Meeting Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "meetings".* FROM "meetings" WHERE "meetings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 224]]
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "meetings" SET "accepted" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "meetings"."id" = ?  [["accepted", "t"], ["updated_at", "2016-11-11 21:05:27.882521"], ["id", 224]]
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb:65:in `update'
```

This was never an issue, and seemingly came out of no where. What is the cause of this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what the issue is.  I've added a line to your update method

```
class MeetingsController < ApplicationController

respond_to :json, :html 

def update
 respond_to do |format|    **error highlights this line**
   if @meeting.update(meeting_params)
     format.html { redirect_to some_rails_path }
     format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @meeting }
   else
     format.html { render :edit }
     format.json { render json: @meeting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end
end
```

The reason you're getting an unknown format error but still successfully updating meeting is because your method has solid logic, so it's updating the meeting, but then once it does that, and you're only telling it what to do in terms of JSON but not in terms of HTML, you address both in your else statement, but not if the update succeeds.

Comment: Okay, got it. This fixed it, but just to clarify the cause so I know for the future - every time it needs to be given directions for both html and json, even if I don't necessarily need a redirect?   Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @gwalshington but you do need a redirect so the app knows what to do on reload. Even if it's just redirect_to :back. If you don't want the page to reload...you need to submit with ajax.

Comment: if you want to render a page after an update...you need a format.html call.

Answer (score 1):

Is this supposed to be an ajax request? It doesn't seem to be. But you're rendering json instead of html. If you're going to allow the page to reload you need to add an html option to `if @meeting.update(meeting_params)`

Something like: `format.html { redirect_to @meeting, notice: 'Meeting was successfully updated.' }`

If you're doing an ajax request this isn't the correct answer, but I don't see any indication in your question that you are. Lmk if you need further clarification.